# Torch: Unable to free gpu memory after moving tensors to cpu

Tags: lua, garbage-collection, torch

Following an idea floated by jcjohnson, in order to generate large images in neural style in a constrained memory environment, I am trying to move layer activations back and forth from gpu to cpu within updateOutput and updateGradInput. e.g.

```
 if (torch.type(previousModule) == 'cudnn.ReLU' or torch.type(previousModule) == 'cudnn.SpatialConvolution') then
    previousModule.output = previousModule.output:cuda()
    collectgarbage('collect')
 end
....
 if (torch.type(currentModule) == 'cudnn.ReLU' or torch.type(currentModule) == 'cudnn.SpatialConvolution') then
    currentModule.output = currentModule.output:float()
    collectgarbage('collect')
 end
```

Functionally, it is working fine for smaller images, the image is generated, albeit slowly. However, even after converting the output tensor to float from cuda, it still does not release the memory in gpu despite explicitly invoking the collectgarbage() routine and I cannot generate images any larger than what were originally constrained by the gpu memory.

Any ideas where I am going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is supposed to work this way. Networks are expected to stay untouched when they run.

`cudnn` has [this](https://github.com/soumith/cudnn.torch#conversion-between-cudnn-and-nn) function that says it performs conversions, there's no clear answer on what happens to memory when module is moved from gpu. (It seems weird that a CPU run functions could work on GPU stored data)

Standard `cunn` module doesn't have the backward conversion for networks at all.

Your code does the following:

```
if currentModule is cuda, then convert its output to float.
previousModule = currentModule
if previousModule is cuda then convert its output to cuda
```

Finally, if your gpu code is slow and you constantly move data back and forth, are you sure it won't be easier to just use cpu.